# Импорт из каталога верхнего уровня python

Tags: python, python-3.x

К своему стыду, споткнулся на детской проблеме и не могу понять вот какую вещь. Допустим есть вот такая структура файлов

```
/project
    /pack
        main.py
    utils.py
```

Я хочу импортировать в файл `main.py` что-нибудь из `utils.py`. Пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
from ..utils import some_function
```

При запуске `main.py` получаю ошибку

> attempted relative import with no known parent package

И не очень понимаю суть этой ошибки. Я знаю, что есть список `sys.path`, в котором лежит список путей, относительно которых питон пытается найти модули. В этот список всегда входит текущий каталог, в котором лежит запускаемый файл. Две точки при импорте означают каталог на уровень выше. В чем тут противоречие и как правильно импортировать функцию в данном случае? Неужели добавлять в `sys.path` верхний каталог самому?

Comment: две точки убрали в третьем питоне

Comment: ну не совсем убрали - наложили ограничения. надо раскидать __init__.py по всем каталогам и то не всегда поможет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Две точки сработают если файл маин был импортирован из каталога выше, и ещё надо чтоб утилс был в пакете.

У меня получился с такой структурой подобный проект.

```
/project
   /pack
      __init__.py
      main.py
   /utils
      __init__.py
      utils.py
   server.py
```

server.py:

```
from pack import main
main.main()
```

main.py

```
from ..utils.utils import some_function
```

Comment: Ну то есть запускаемый файл должен лежать всегда на верхнем уровне получается,  а если надо импортировать из верхнего уровня, то надо в sys.path добавлять. Я понял, буду знать.

Comment: и `..` это спуск из `pack.main` а не из каталога

Comment: да-да, это я понял. Единственное чего я не понял - почему это так. Безопасность?

Comment: оно изначально задумывалось как спуск из модуля.

во втором питоне это почти эквивалентно было. в третьем питоне загрузчик модулей не привязан к папке и модуль может быть объявлен `pack.main.py` спуск из него уже не спуск по папкам.