# Запуск unit-тестов из python-модуля, не расположенного в каталоге с тестируемыми модулями

Tags: python, юнит-тесты, импорт, python-import

Существует следующая структура каталогов:

```
project_dir/
   scripts/
      script.py
   tests/
      test.py
```

Модуль test.py содержит unit-тесты для функций из script.py. Необходимо, используя pytest, запустить test.py из корневого каталога проекта **project_dir/**. Следовательно, в модуле test.py необходимо импортировать модуль script.py.

Как собственно это сделать?

Пробую запускать так: `pytest tests/test.py`, в test.py модуль пытаюсь импортировать так: `import ..scripts.convert_qserv` или же `from ..scripts.convert_qserv import *` (`..` применяю, т.к. видел похожее подтвержденное решение на [*вопрос со stackoverflow*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042355/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8F-python)). Собственно выдает ошибку `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'` в первом случае и `ImportError: attemped relative import with no known parent package` во втором.

Работаю на Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте файл `__init__.py` в директории `tests`. Сделайте импорт

```py
from scripts.convert_qserv import *
```